# AS3 add font style to fontlist

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a drop down list of fonts and would like to add the font to each fontname i.e so Helvetica looks like Helvetica in the list etc...

```
allFonts=[new Font1(),new Font2(),new Font3(),new Font4()];

        for (var i:int=0; i<allFonts.length; i++)
        {
            panel.fontList.addItem({label:allFonts[i].fontName});
        }
```

Comment: How did you made your dropdown list ? Did you make it yourself ? Is it a flash component ? Please be more precise if you want help.